# Importing data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Using http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archives/view/fodean_eh_2012/downloads.cfm.

How do I import data using qgis?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] which explains how the site works.  You are expected to have looked at the relevant documentation prior to posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Download all zip files and unzip them.

Then drag and drop all `.shp` files into the table of content of a new QGIS project.

If you want a nice background map, install the openlayers plugin, select `EPSG:3857` as **project** CRS, and select a Google or Openstreetmap background.